# Wildcards in uBlock Origin network filters? (in the path)

Tags: ublock-origin

I use business’s customer area of a site, that tries to circumvent ad blockers, by using random IDs in its resource URLs. E.g.

`a.storyblok.com/f/116218/1120x850/b403b00e1d/kundenportal-banner-desktop_zoe-gas_stromee_gas_announcement_desktop-copy-3.png`

Where `b403b00e1d` is random hex number that changes every time.

I tried to create a filter, using the built-in UI, and replacing the hash by a wildcard, like so:

`||a.storyblok.com/f/116218/1120x850/*/kundenportal-banner-desktop_zoe-gas_stromee_gas_announcement_desktop-copy-3.png$image`

But it does nothing.

The documentation does not even mention wildcards in the path. Only in the domain part. But the documentation generally is quite the mess. So I’m not sure this is even available at all or if I’m doing something wrong.

I can’t use a cosmetic filter, because everything is generic, and the only part that lets me tell the difference, is the image itself. So blocking the generic patterns would block things I *do* want to see. (They intermix their stupid borderline-harassing newsletter ads with important contract info that might be expensive to ignore. In 2023. Two decades after newsletter e-mails died a deserved death.)

I have looked through the possible duplicates for this question, and nothing fits.

Comment: No solution, but i can confirm wildcards are not only working for domains. I have a rule like `||domain.tld/ad/*.png$image` which does work to block any images located in this directory. Seeing you block a random path but still leave a distinct filename in that rule - might that be a problem there?

Comment: Wildcards mentioned here: https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Filter-Performance#narrowing-options-for-network-filters
They do work and are widely used in easylist
Can't spot your error though

Answer (score 0):

You can always try [regex-based filter](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Regular-expression-based-filters), e.g.:

```
/http:\/\/a\.storyblok\.com\/f\/d+\/\d+x\d+\/[a-z\d]+\/.*?\.png/$domain=somesite.com
```

where `somesite.com` is the website where the ads occur, `\d+` is any number of digits, `[a-z\d]+` is an number of digits orsmall letters and `.*?` is anything non-greedily until `.png` extension. It can be narrowed down further or less, if needed.